# Embed in Discord.js send also the command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a discord.js announcement bot ex. When I write ?Ann Hello Guys the bot delete my message and send Hello Guys but now if I write ?Ann Hello Guys the bot delete my message and send *?Ann Hello Guys* the code is this

```
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('--------------');

const PREFIX = '?';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Questo bot e online!');
});

client.on('message', message=>{

    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

    switch(args[0]){
        case 'ann':
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addField('test', message.content  );
        message.channel.send(embed);
    break;
}

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a pen for this: 
https://codepen.io/herbievine/pen/YzwNewQ

```
client.on('message', message=>{

    let args

    if (message.startsWith('?')) 
      args = message.content.replace('?', '').split(' ')

    if (args[0].toLowerCase() === 'ann') {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .addField('test', message.contentreplace('?ann', ''));
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}

})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: *messsage.startsWith is not a function*

Comment: message.content.startsWith() ? sorry, don't really know where the string is...

Answer (score 0):

`message.content` represents the whole message that you are sending, so in this case will be `?Ann Hello Guys`.

DiscordJS doesn't understand what commands are, and it doesn't split this stuff out for you.

As your message is formatted as `?Mention <Command arguments here>` you can split it via the space within the string.

`let messageContent = message.content.split(" ")`

This takes your string of `"?Ann Hello Guys"` and turns it into `"?Ann", "Hello", "Guys"`

`.split(" ")` separates your string via the spaces, and returns an array.

You can then do `messageContent.pop()` to remove the first element in the array, which is `"?Ann"`.

You can then `.join(" ")` these back together, forming the string `"Hello Guys"` and send that. Fully formed code:

```
let splitMessage = message.content.split(" ")

splitMessage.pop();

const transformedMessage = splitMessage.join(" ")
```

Comment: same thing it sends *?ann Hello World*